# Invalid parameter: redirect_uri - KEYCLOAK

Tags: flask, keycloak

[This error keep on persisting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koQ2k.png)

[Keycloak Client settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIdav.png)

[client_secrets.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE1u3.png)

[my python app file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbVNi.png)

I wanted to authenticate flask app using keycloak but this error keeps on persisting
I am unable to figure out
http://localhost:8080/realms/dendrite/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=Todo&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Foidc%2Fcallback&scope=openid+email+profile&access_type=offline&response_type=code&state=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjogInRkRkJqdzJKYTM4NEEyQ2lNYzZPLVBpaEdoTG42X1lEIiwgImRlc3RpbmF0aW9uIjogImV5SmhiR2NpT2lKSVV6VXhNaUo5LkltaDBkSEE2THk4eE1qY3VNQzR3TGpFNk5UQXdNQzhpLi03MlBwenRkWXZFb2kxY2UyU3NUUzRXSWRGTGRselppelg4b0lERUJiTkx5SVR5NU1ZaXprWTBhUkxaS3FtczNDY29TUEJtcnhQLUo1dUlHRDNlRVF3In0%3D
This is the link redirected when the flask app is run